# Ansible, "cisco.ios.ios_ospf_interfaces": How can I get this plugin?

Tags: ansible

I'm running Ansible version 2.9.14 and I've already downloaded the "cisco.ios" Ansible collection.  However, when I look in my directory, "**ansible_collections/cisco/ios/plugins/modules**"  I don't seem to have a .py file for ios_ospf_interfaces. Consequently when I include a task in a playbook that references this module the task produces an error.

I tried to install the cisco.ios collection again, but my system reported it already had this collection and didn't do anything further. So how can I get this particular module on my system?

Thanks!

[Existing Ansible Modules On My System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOsoJ.png)

Comment: Hi Keith, welcome to SO. You will need to specify which [version of the `cisco.ios` collection](https://github.com/ansible-collections/cisco.ios/releases) you installed, since it matters

Comment: The only way I've found to determine the version of this collection was to try to use the command, "ansible-galaxy collection verify cisco.ios -vvv" but my version of ansible doesn't seem to support the "verify" keyword. The only available keywords it supports for ansible-galaxy are, "init, build, publish & install".  Any other ideas for determining the version of this Collection?

Comment: If you `ansible-galaxy collection install -vv cisco.ios:==1.2.0` does the status change?

Comment: Awesome!  That was it!  I was using version 1.1.0 of cisco.ios.  When I used your command above with the --force argument it updated it to 1.2.0 and now I see that module I was missing!  Thanks again mdaniel!

Answer (score 0):

(**credit for this answer goes to mdaniel**)
When using the standard command, "ansible-galaxy collection install cisco.ios" it's possible that you may not receive the latest version of this collection.

In this instance, the version of the collection that was installed on my system was 1.1.0 and yet to obtain the "ios_ospf_interfaces" module I needed 1.2.0

To verify the current version of the cisco.ios module the command is:

```
ansible-galaxy collection install -vv cisco.ios:==1.2.0
```

If the output displays that you are running an earlier version of this collection, repeat the command above but add the argument, "--force" at the end to force it to update to version 1.2.0